# .NET Framework 4.5 : SMTP Client authentication modes?

Tags: c#, smtp, md5

Has someone found an official reference of which SMTP authentication modes are actually supported by the `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` class please?

Official MSDN seems silent on that one ; if not, where can I find a suitable SMTP client library (free or not)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the source code, it looks like only LOGIN is supported unless FEATURE_PAL is defined (not sure what that is), in which case NTLM, GSSAPI, and WDIGEST are also supported.

You can take a look at Microsoft's referencesource here: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/d925d870f3cb3f6acdb14e71522ece7054e2233b/System/net/System/Net/mail/SmtpTransport.cs

Comment: Thanks, my application using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient of the 4.5 Framework gets 'Authentication failed' when trying establishing a Smtp client connection on a ESMTP mail server (server Smtp auth order : 250- AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5).

Comment: Based on that, the only auth mechanism that SmtpClient will try is LOGIN.

Comment: In general, SMTP servers will not allow LOGIN until/unless the channel is encrypted via SSL.

Comment: Thanks, I dit not know that. I'll check if the SSL boolean parameter is set or not during test of SMTP connection using LOGIN authentication mode.

Comment: With the following parametrization , my application fails to connect to SMTP server but Thunderbird built-in messaging manages it.  
Host : 127.0.0.1, smtp user : username , pass : pwd , ssl : off, port : 25. In each case LOGIN mode is the one used .... my application works with Gmail, Yahoo mail, MS Exc ... but it seems to fail with this local HMC mail server when authenticating with LOGIN mode.

Comment: Sounds like your user name or password is incorrect

Comment: Thanks again for your help jstedfast,  I'll have to create a local SMTP server which uses LOGIN authentication mode to see what's what. The .NET default stack is not really explicit with only a symbolic 'Authentication failed' as Exception message; I'll inject a logger class and maybe change the SMTP library in order to follow SMTP conversation exchange between client and server ; speaking of which, would you mind pointing me towards such a reliable library if you know any? My .NET 4.0 applications must work with older SMTP systems ( commissionned in early '00 )